# Can I create an ember computed property from a jquery function?

Tags: jquery, css, ember.js

I'm trying to bind two tables together so that the widths and heights of their elements are the same. Unfortunately, whenever I measure the width/height of the source table, I'm always getting an intermediate value before the browser changes the cell to match the data. It would be great if I could create a computed property from jquery's width and height methods. Something like:

```
width: ( ->
  @$().width()
).property('@$().width()')
```

Is this even possible? It seems like I should be able to call jquery somewhere in the run loop, compare to the last value of width, and send elementDidChange if they're different. But, I have no idea how to do that ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't attach it like so.

You can attach to a list of events on the view.

http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/#toc_adding-new-events

set the width on `didInsertElement`, and you can also do it `afterRender` which shouldn't run until after everything is rendered giving you a good size.

```
App.FooView = Em.View.extend({
  setupWidth: function(){
    var el = this.$(),
        self = this;
    this.set('width', self.width());
    Em.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', function(){
      self.set('width', self.width());
    });
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

Additionally you could hook up an additional event for if the window changes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But, doesn't `resize` only fire when the window resizes?

Comment: You know what, I have no idea, I thought it was available for all elements, but I've never tried it, you're probably right.  I'll look into it.

Comment: You might try the adjusted answer, is it just a cell in a table that's resizing to fit the data?

Comment: Unfortunately, that approach does not work ... well, it doesn't work for my current tables. I've been letting the `td` widths expand to fit the data. I think(tm) this is returning the width before the cell has resized to fit the data. That's why I was trying to bind to the resize event because the cells seem to be resizing well after they are inserted.  I'm going to try locking down the table style so that it doesn't change as much (or at all).